# Are "var" and "variant" the same thing?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

From what I understand, to make a property an array in QML you must specify it as the type `variant` or `var`:

`property var myArray:[]`

And this appears to be exactly the same as:

`property variant myArray:[]`

Is this true?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Qt 5.0 variant documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-variant.html):

> The variant type is a generic property type. It is obsolete and exists only to support old applications; new applications should use [var](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-var.html) type properties instead.

So yes, it is the same, but you should always stick to `var` (unless you got an earlier version which does not support that yet).

Comment: Thanks; am I correct that using `var` is the only way to make array properties?

Comment: At least the only way I know of

Comment: This is indeed the documentation; I'm just surprised that QtCreator (as of 3.6.1) does not in any way warn the user that `variant` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a completely new answer, but contains additional information about the answer provided by @Tim Meyer, based on my own experience:

1. With Qt 4.* or QtQuick 1.*, `property variant` has to be used otherwise QML parsing errors will be produced.
2. With Qt 5 or QtQuick 2.*, either `property variant` or `property var` can be used. But the latter one is recommended, as the former one is being deprecated.
3. Qt 4 `property variant` or Qt 5 `property var` may be used for QML array or list declaration/definition. But if the type and unchangeable content of `myArray` are known in advance, `property list<Type>` can also be used. For example:

   property list<`Item`> myArray: [ Item {}, Item {} ]